# Google Maps javascript Directions error direction.display.setMap(map)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps-api-3

When I try to enter the system location of google in my map it is not working. The screen stays blank. When I raise the string " `directionsDisplay.setMap ( map ) ;` " the map is displayed but does not work.
Why ? I'll post the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/x1115zw3/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
 var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4184,-122.0880);
 map.setCenter(pos);
 directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

put "directionsDisplay.setMap(map);" this line after DirectionRender as mentioned above

http://jsfiddle.net/x1115zw3/3/